# Why can we use an instance of a custom/foundation class in the implementation of a method without first doing alloc and init for the instance?

Tags: objective-c

This question is based on the code from the first lecture in the Stanford iOS series 2014 (objective - c).

We created a class called `Card` which includes a method named `match:` which will be used to determine how different cards will match up against one another in the game, and this method takes as an argument an `NSArray` called `*otherCards` and we use an instance of `Card` called `*card` to iterate through this array in the implementation of this method.

My question is this - how can we just declare an instance of our class Card i.e `*card` and use it as an iterating variable in the for loop without first allocating and instantiating it? In the same vein, how can we just declare *otherCards as an instance of NSArray and then use it in the cycling through of the for loop before it is allocated and initialised also?

I realise this might be done later in the code, but why isn't the compiler throwing at least a warning about this?

Here is the code:

```
//Card.h

@interface Card : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents; 
@property (nonatomic, getter=isChosen) BOOL chosen;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isMatched) BOOL matched;

- (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards;



    //Card.m

  #import "Card.h"

    @implementation Card
    - (int)match:(NSArray *)otherCards
    {


        int score = 0; 
    for (Card *card in otherCards) { 
    if ([card.contents isEqualToString:self.contents ])
    {
            score = 1;
        }

        }

        return score;
    }


    @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is about this loop:

```
for (Card *card in otherCards) {
    ...
}
```

> how can we just declare *otherCards as an instance of NSArray and then use it

You don't need to alloc and init `otherCards` because it is supplied as a parameter to the function `match`. The caller is responsible for initializing it. You can't dodge initialization, just that it's done elsewhere:

```
Card * myCard = ...               // init the varible here
NSArray * otherCards = ...        // init the array here
int n = [myCard match:otherCards] // otherCards is now initialized. Don't need to 
                                  // do it again inside your method
```

> how can we just declare an instance of our class `Card` i.e `*card` and use it as an iterating variable in the `for` loop

`card` is not a new object. It just points existing objects inside the `otherCards` array, hence no need to alloc and init.

You did declare `card` as a pointer of type `Card` in the `for` loop: `for (Card * card in otherCards)`. This is a syntactic sugar to make code more concise. You can do it the long way if you want:

```
Card * card;
for (card in otherCards) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`…(NSArray *)otherCards` and `Card *card in`are both placeholders.

`otherCards` is a parameter name. The method `match` expects an (initialized) NSArray as parameter to process the array locally in the method. The associated pointer `(NSArray *)` holds the reference to the array until the method is left.

`Card *card in` is a temporary index pointer which holds the reference to one (initialized) item of the array per iteration

Answer (score 1):

The instances do exist; these are just the local names that you're using for them. You're right that nothing would happen if they hadn't been created first, but it's not this method's job to create them.

There is no compiler warning because you've done nothing wrong at compile time: you've taken an object of type `NSArray` and iterated through it (using the `for( ... in theArray )` syntax), with a temporary name for each of its members. It's possible for that array to not exist (be `nil`) at runtime, but there's no way for the ObjC compiler to know that; and even if it happened, the result would simply be nothing, not an error.

Later code using this method will look something like this:

```
Card * aCard = [[Card alloc] init];
// set aCard's properties
NSArray * cards = @[anotherCard, aThirdCard, stillAnotherCard];
[card match:cards];
```

Where all these objects are created and then *passed in* to the method as needed.

Comment: Sorry I can't choose two accepted answers, they were both equally helpful. Appreciate your answer.